# How to convert EM fields to EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

How a body producing electricity and magnetic fields become a body radiating electromagnetic waves?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_%28radio%29

Answer (score 1):

You just need to oscillate the body.  That can mean oscillating the charge on it, by oscillating the current to it; then body becomes an antenna.  Or, you can literally wiggle the body back and forth, and it will radiate.  The frequency with which you oscillate the body becomes the frequency of the waves, and the wavelength is c/f, so you have to oscillate it at frequencies of 100's of kHz or more to get radio waves, and millions of kHz to get the microwaves that cell phones use.